# Code sign failed when working with Jenkins of my iOS project

Tags: jenkins, xcodebuild, codesign

I run my Jenkins on a linux server. Because the xcodebuild command cannot run on it, I set up a mac slave for it. I'm using cocoapods so I add a execute shell step in the build section: 
[image: like this]

But while starting a build task on Jenkins. I keep getting code sign errors like bellow

```
CodeSign /Users/minghaoxue/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClubFactory-cjjgomahwcoblcaqbnubetcloubb/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/ClubFactory.app/Frameworks/AWSCognito.framework (in target: ClubFactory)
cd /Users/Shared/Jenkins/workspace/club_factory_ad_hoc
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate

Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: Minghao xue (MU2PM44A6U)"

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 5B937C4F106A71C5958593769FADD3D8E195F888 --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements,flags --timestamp=none /Users/minghaoxue/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClubFactory-cjjgomahwcoblcaqbnubetcloubb/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/ClubFactory.app/Frameworks/AWSCognito.framework/Users/minghaoxue/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ClubFactory-cjjgomahwcoblcaqbnubetcloubb/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/ClubFactory.app/Frameworks/AWSCognito.framework: errSecInternalComponent
```

I think I have do the right configure for code-sign related things. Could someone give a hand on this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the XCode plugin?

[Xcode plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin)

It states:

> Signing
>
> This plugin has two features that help you simplify the code signing process.

Comment: Yes, I first tried Xcode plugin. But It can't set the build scheme parameter with it. Because I want to build the target with workspace.